# How to get index of array of object without using loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get index of from array of objects without using loop as per the key name using PHP. Here I am explaining my code below.

```
$arr = array(array("name"=>"Jack","ID"=>10),array("name"=>"Jam","ID"=>11),array("name"=>"Joy","ID"=>12));
$key = array_search('Jack', $arr);

echo $key;exit;
```

Here my code does not give any output. By using some key name I need the index of that object present inside array and also I dont want to use any loop. I need Is ther any PHP in build method so that I can get the result directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array(array("name"=>"Jack","ID"=>10),array("name"=>"Jam","ID"=>11),array("name"=>"Joy","ID"=>12));

function myfunction($v){return  $v['name'];}
echo array_search('Jack', array_map( 'myfunction', $arr ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = array(array("name"=>"Jack","ID"=>10),array("name"=>"Jam","ID"=>11),array("name"=>"Joy","ID"=>12));

//calling function searchByName
$key = searchByName('Jasck',$arr);

if($key != '-1'){
  print_r($arr[$key]);  
}else{
    echo "No match found";
}

//function to chek if the name is there or not.
function searchByName($name, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['name'] == $name) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return '-1';
}
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6704d960ee81eaa872b9d6064c6f7b553f27e9eb)

Comment: You used again here loop.